# Autodesk Forge Viewer Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue when running on local server

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to run the autodesk viewer from a local tomcat server at port 8080.
The drawing comes up, but it is untextured. Looking at the chrome console I get the following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load     https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/res/environments/SharpHighlights_irr.logluv.dds.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://developer-autodesk.github.io' that is not equal to the
>   supplied origin.    Origin '...localhost:8080' is therefore not
>   allowed access

I am not sure what is adding the header. Is there something I need to modify in the linked autodesk forge viewer javascript files that will fix this?

Note that my localhost server is not https

Comment: "I am not sure what is adding the header" — That would be the code that runs developer.api.autodesk.com

Comment: are you using the tutorial from https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/ ?

Comment: please also double check the developer-autodesk.GITHUB.io reference.. should not be there.